# mysql case satisfies more than one condition

Tags: mysql, case

I am wondering which condition in the case is going to be used by the system, assuming that more that one condition is satisfied.

```
 CASE 
    WHEN id IN($cID) THEN `count`+1
    WHEN id IN($prev_catID) THEN `count`-1  
 END
```

Will it be the first one, or the last?

In the other programming, there is a BREAK added to each condition to terminate the process. Does the BREAK will do in mysql?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `case` statement is evaluated sequentially.  The first matching statement is the one that is returned.

This is pretty clearly described in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html):

> For the second syntax, each WHEN clause search_condition expression is
>   evaluated until one is true, at which point its corresponding THEN
>   clause statement_list executes. If no search_condition is equal, the
>   ELSE clause statement_list executes, if there is one.